# Pushing strings to C++ from MASM

Tags: c++, assembly, masm, masm32

So i'm attempting to make the game of Tik Tak Toe in MASM 32 bit but I cannot figure out how to pass a string from MASM to C++ to output text to the console. Any help would be much appreciated.

C++

```
// main.cpp
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

extern "C" void asmMain();
extern "C" void printString(string msg);

int main() {
    asmMain();
    return 0;
}

void printString(string msg)
{
    cout << msg << endl;
}
```

Masm

```
.386
.MODEL FLAT, stdcall
.STACK 4096

printString PROTO C
.DATA
sIntroMessage BYTE "Welcome To Tik Tak Toe!"

.CODE
asmMain PROC C
    mov ecx, sIntroMessage
    call printString
asmMain ENDP
END
```

Comment: Use C strings and not C++ strings which are way more complicated.

Comment: Make sure you follow the calling convention which for stdcall requires the caller to pass parameters on the stack. Look at disassembly to get a better idea

Answer (score 1):

I'm Assuming you're using Microsoft's C/C++ compiler and assembler and if I recall the default calling convention is cdecl not stdcall mentioned in the comments. The stdcall directive in your assembly file applies if someone were to call your function from C/C++. In your assembly code if your functions take arguments then you need to ret the number of arguments*4. Assuming printString is cdecl, you need to push the arguments onto the stack instead of moving it to ecx then restore the stack pointer after the call is made.

```
.386
.MODEL FLAT, stdcall
.STACK 4096

printString PROTO C
.DATA
sIntroMessage BYTE "Welcome To Tik Tak Toe!"

.CODE
asmMain PROC C
    lea ecx, sIntroMessage
    push ecx
    call printString
    add esp,4
asmMain ENDP
END
```

Also mentioned in the comments your printString function should instead take a `char*` argument rather than a string object. Unless you want to construct the string object yourself in your assembly file which is more work and tedious.

```
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

extern "C" void asmMain();
extern "C" void printString(char* msg);

int main() {
    asmMain();
    return 0;
}

void printString(char* msg)
{
    cout << msg << endl;
}
```